# Programmatically getting a node input slider's max and min

Tags: python, scripting, node-editor

I have already asked this question [HERE](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/165056/how-to-get-the-max-and-min-value-of-a-certain-nodesocket), but it was actually not answered before it got closed as someone thought it was a duplicate. I now know that I can find a `soft_max` and `soft_min` parameter of a NodeSocket, which helps somewhat, but it does **not** solve it. Why? Because the `soft_max` and `soft_min` do not at all correspond to the sliders' max and min. Basically all float value sockets have a `soft_max` and `soft_min` of 10000 and -10000, but some of the sliders range between [0,10] or [0, 2] or anything. This range is what I'm interested, and wondering if it is at all possible to find it programmatically. Thank you :D

Comment: The slider range should match `soft_min` and `soft_max`, do you have an example where this isn't the case?

Comment: Rather than asking the same question again _"I have already asked this question [HERE](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/165056/how-to-get-the-max-and-min-value-of-a-certain-nodesocket)"_  (a self confessed dupe) recommend you edit your previous question and reveal the identity of the _"certain nodesocket"_.   This will flag the question for re-opening. The two commenters here are the  _"someones"_ who voted to close your question.  Happy to vote to re-open.

Comment: @RobertGützkow https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/165056/how-to-get-the-max-and-min-value-of-a-certain-nodesocket#comment279001_165061

Comment: @batFINGER I'm aware of the duplicate question, but it's not clear where this node is from. Could be from the Grove add-on?

Comment: Hi @batFINGER. Thanks for the help, but when a thread is marked as a dupe, stackexchange tells me that "If this question doesn’t resolve your question, ask a new one.", which is what I did. Anyway, I'll edit that one and give more information (y)!